# How to combine data if the a table returns multiple rows in a select?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a sql database and query like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10af9/3

As you can see, I have a few users who have a few favorite colors.  What I would like to be able to do is run a query through and select all the users and their favorite colors... however, for ease of use in my own code, I would like there not to be duplicate data on each row.

What I would like is for the end result to be:

```
1   |  Email  | admin@sqlfiddle.com | [Blue, Green]
2   | Twitter | @sqlfiddle          | [Purple]
```

That way I am returned is a table of users, where every row is a user, and I can get their favorite color.

If there's a different way of thinking about this (not combining, but ending up with a table of users and their favorite colors on ONE row), I'd love to hear that too.

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?  The SQL Fiddle is MySQL, so I'm inclined to think that is the appropriate database.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to add that.  MySQL is indeed the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will do exactly what you want.

```
select 
  supportContacts.id, 
  supportContacts.type, 
  supportContacts.details, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(favoriteColors.color)
from supportContacts 
left join favoriteColors on supportContacts.id = favoriteColors.support_id
group by supportContacts.id
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Fiddle is MySQL, so I'm assuming that is the database.  In MySQL, you can put them together using `group_concat()`:

```
select sc.id, sc.type, sc.details,
       group_concat(fc.color)
from supportContacts sc left join
     favoriteColors fc
     on sc.id = fc.support_id
group by sc.id, sc.type, sc.details;
```

If you really want them in the format with the square braces:

```
       concat('[', group_concat(fc.color separator ', '), ']')
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10af9/5) is the SQL Fiddle.

Other databases generally have similar functionality.